# How can I get into my Xiaomi Poco M2 (bootloader locked) that won't boot

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, boot-loop, xiaomi, miui-12.5

I uninstalled the **'com.xiaomi.finddevice'** package from my phone and on the next reboot the phone spent 5 minutes displaying the miui logo and then went to the recovery menu on its own.The recovery menu had options for : safe mode(which behaved the same as normal boot),wipe full data(not just the cache part.),reboot,*mi assistant*(which is to connect the phone to a pc using the *MiPcSuite*).

I tried the MiPcSuite but it wouldn't discover the device even though windows recognized it as a adb interface.I tried to access it separately from adb but the device was showed as locked.What I was trying to do was to somehow reinstall the package.

As far as I could figure out,the device needed to be turned on for me to access it via an adb shell(though usb debugging was enabled and my pc authorized the last time it booted) and fastboot had no such provision.

I was apprehensive of trying TWRP as the xda guide called for the bootloader to be unlocked prior to flashing. My device is not rooted, nor is the bootloader unlocked.I'm pretty sure the only thing preventing it from booting is the  'com.xiaomi.finddevice' package being uninstalled.

My device is a Xiaomi Poco M2 running android 11 and miui 12.5

Is there any way to reinstall the package or otherwise repair the device so it turns on or at least to retrieve my data.

Comment: run adb logcat during boot